# How to import base classes correctly

Tags: python, import

I am trying to write a library (sort of) for my project. I would like to keep it as modularized as possible. I have a `main.py` in the root directory and I have two packages required for running the main. I am calling them `package1` and `package2`. The packages in each of them will inherit from their own base packages. The overall tree is as following:

```
.
├── main.py
├── package1
│   ├── base_package1.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main_package1.py
└── package2
    ├── base_package2.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main_package2.py
```

In the file for each package, I am also writing the code to test them. But to test package 2, I also need package 1. My question is about how to import package 1 to package 2. `main.py` is currently empty. I will share the contents of the remaining files here.

```py
# package1/__init__.py

from .main_package1 import *
```

```py
# package1/base_package1.py

class BasePackage1:
    def __init__(self):
        print("init base package 1")
```

```py
# package1/main_package1.py

from base_package1 import BasePackage1

class MainPackage1(BasePackage1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("init main package 1")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Test MainPackage1
    pkg = MainPackage1()
```

```py
# package2/base_package2.py

class BasePackage2:
    def __init__(self):
        print("init base package 2")
```

```py
# package2/main_package2.py

from base_package2 import BasePackage2

class MainPackage2(BasePackage2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("init main package 2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Option 1
    import sys
    sys.path.append("../")
    from package1 import MainPackage1

    # Error:
    # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base_package1'

    # Option 2
    from ..package1 import MainPackage1

    # Error:
    # ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

What is the correct way to do this? Is there a standard way to do this?

---

Update: I have found a solution that works for now and posted it as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72930898/6211109) below. If you have a better solution, please post it.

Comment: Your tree is fine for *development*, but for distribution, `main.py` should be installed as a script (say `/usr/local/bin/main.py`) and the packages as libraries (say `/usr/local/lib/python/site-packages/package{1,2}`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you. I may not be deploying the whole thing as a package. This is for a research project that would be on Github. But I want it to be clean and easy-to-use.

Comment: try looking at the answers from the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

In package2/base_package2.py if you want to reference `package1.base_package1` you can import that directly as your current reference point is where `main.py` is. Absolute imports (those which don't start with a dot) start from your working directory, so you can import `package1` from anywhere in `package2` and it will be the same.

The reason why you get

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

is because you are running `package2/base_package.py` as a main file, which would run as its own script. However, you have provided three files with paths given as `package2/base_package.py`. I'm assuming that the ones with `__main__` are actually `main_package1` and `main_package2` respectively.

Comment: I don't know if I understood your comment fully. The `__main__`'s are in `main_package1.py` and `main_package2.py`. I tried `from package1.main_package1 import MainPackage1` in `main_package2.py`, but got the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1'`.

Comment: In your question, you don;t specify the contents of `package1/main_package1.py` and instead list 3 codeblocks with titles of `# package2/base_package2.py`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, @Ray. I had copy-pasted those headers. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few other things, I found a solution that seems to be work. I will post it here but **will not select it as the accepted answer in case someone comes up with a better and more elegant solution**.

In `package2/main_package2.py`, I did the following import:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("../package1")
from main_package1 import MainPackage1
```

Comment: Modifying `sys.path` is almost always a bad idea, as `..` could reference anywhere depending on where you run the script.